# Scaling With Session Data in Database

Tags: php, mysql, session, silex

My Silex app has always had the session data stored on the server, but I want to move to the mysql database so that I'm not so tied to a single webserver. I'm wondering about performance, though. I plan to use the PdoSessionHandler. My question is this: currently I have about 177K stored sessions. Will the garbage collection be slow? Will I be taking a performance hit by moving to the database from the filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you going to have an index on the session expiry? If there is no index, then yes, it will be slow. OTOH, how fast do you think searching 177,000 files on disk is? Probably a *lot* slower than using a database to do the thing it is expressly designed to do.

Will you take a performance hit? Probably. Will it be significant? Depends what else the system is doing with the database, the configuration of the DB, and the server it runs on.

In short - yes, there will be an inevitable cost to use the database as a session store, but it could be worth it for the abilities it gives you.

I'd suggest using Redis, backed to disk though.

Comment: Redis is a great option for session management.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, using a MySQL database as the defacto session storage in the name of scaling is about one of the worst mistakes you can make in distributed session storage.

Let me explain why...

1. Your MySQL database is likely already your biggest bottleneck in that PHP probably connects to it for just about everything else persistent anyway. However, there are probably a handful of request URIs where PHP might be relying on cache and not hitting your db. In the case that you're using sessions on those pages (well, there goes your connection overhead again).
2. The cost of deleting rows from a large table (in your case for GC) in MySQL can be extremely expensive at scale. In MyISAM the entire table is locked (worst outcome the entire site blocks during a large GC cycle). With InnoDB the DBMS has to write all of your undo information to a large commit log taking up added I/O and sometimes causing sluggishness depending on fragmentation issues. This could especially prove problematic if you have re-indexing issues too.
3. There are already better alternatives and they require you to write *less* code!

My recommendation is to just use something like [memcached](http://php.net/memcached) instead. Where the connection overhead can be significantly lower, there are no db schemas to write, and the drivers for the session handler already exist in PHP by default. Throw something like [igbinary](https://php.net/igbinary) on top of memcached and you have blazing fast serialization coupled with cheaper in-memory session handling that can easily be scaled up and distributed with minimal effort and side effects. For example, AWS offers you Elasticache for memcached/redis load-balancing and replication solution in their PaS. There's also [Twem Prox](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) if you're not on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably pivot to storing session data in Redis. It serves blazing fast queries via memory, but it can also recover and repopulate the memory after a crash from a static log.